# What do you call this kind of hairstyle? Is there a specific term for it? (Like marcel waves and such?)

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, terminology, image-identification

[image: screenshot of Mary Poppins]

One of my characters has a similar hairstyle to Mary Poppins. I can't find the specific term though. Can anyone help me identify it?

Answer (score 2):

Well. I've had a quick vada at your pic and I fancy she's had her riah done in a [Gibson girl bun](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Gibson-Girl-Bun), or possibly a [double Gibson](http://www.freckled-fox.com/2013/12/holiday-hair-week-double-gibson.html) with a faint suspicion of "[Heidi rolls](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2285748/Heidi-rolls-latest-hair-trend--Heres-home.html)", or is it me?

Comment: And I was considering answering with," This iquestion is better suited for Movies & TV SE.." where I would've readily answered "Bouffant" (unsure of spelling)

Comment: Surely a bouffant would be puffed up on top? - which certainly doesn't describe the hairdo in the picture.

Comment: Yea i didn't want to worry about accuracy, it was the word that someone used when i did an image search, this site shouldnt stray into picture identification IMHO